MimeMesage object throw exception
I created a class library project to send emails using MimeKit and MailKit.

Project Target framework - .NET Framework 4.7.2

MimeKit version - 4.6.0

MailKit version - 4.6.0


public class MailProcess
  {
      public MailProcess()
       {
          var mimeMessage = new MimeMessage();
       }
  }

I created another Console Application project to call the mail function.

Project Target framework - .NET Framework 4.7.2

I tried to create MimeMessage object using the below code, but it throws an exception
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var mailProcess = new MailProcess();
        }
    }


System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

exception-screenshot
How can I fix this issue?
When I installed MimeKit, version - 4.6.0, the below dependencies also installed automatically

BouncyCastle.Cryptography, version - 2.3.1

System.Buffers, version - 4.5.1

System.Memory, version - 4.5.5

System.Numerics.Vectors, version - 4.5.0

System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, version - 6.0.0


NOTE - The object was created successfully when I tried to create the MimeMessage object inside the class library project (the same project installed Mimekit and Mailkit). There are no errors.

Can't reproduce. Please edit the question so that it supplies a minimal reproducible example.

Which version of MimeKit, MailKit are you using?

Have you installed the "CompilerServices.Unsafe" nuget package?

@PeterCsala MimeKit and MailKit version is - 4.6.0

@Ralf Yes i installed

MimeKit 4.6.0 requires 6.0.0 or newer System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe library. Is there any other library which is using unsafe? Could you please run dotnet list package command and update your question with outcome?

Still can't reproduce.

On which .NET version do you experience the issue?

@MarkSeemann .NET Framework 4.7.2

The System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe v6.0.0 nuget package actually contains System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll with AssemblyVersion attributes of 4.0.4.1

The solution is to create an app.config file in your project that includes a binding redirect for System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.
I believe that it should look something like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>

